# JS. Смена классов по содержимому

Tags: javascript, классы

Есть html:

```
<div class="my-class-1">user-1</div>
<div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
<div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
<div class="my-class-1">user-1</div>
<div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
```

Возможно ли как то изменить классы через JS из my-class-1 на my-class-2 где содержимое блока user-2?

Answer (score 1):

или еще проще:

```js
var items = document.body.querySelectorAll('.my-class-1');

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  var item = items[i];
  if(item.innerHTML === "user-2"){ 
      if( item.className === "my-class-1" ){
        item.className = "my-class-2"; 
      }
  } 
}
```

```css
.my-class-2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="my-class-1">user-1</div>
  <div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
  <div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
  <div class="my-class-1">user-1</div>
  <div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = document.body.querySelectorAll(".my-class-1");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (!(items[i].innerHTML).indexOf('user-2')) { 
    items[i].className = "my-class-2";   
  }
}
```

```css
.my-class-2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class-1">user-1</div>
<div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
<div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
<div class="my-class-1">user-3</div>
<div class="my-class-1">user-2</div>
```

Comment: у элементов нет аттрибута _my-class-1_, поэтому `removeAttribute` тут не поможет

Comment: @Grundy пардон, осталось от предыдущего варианта...

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = document.body.querySelectorAll( '.my-class-1' );
let length = items.length;

const TEXT_CONTENT_PATTERN = "user-2";

for( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
  let item = items[ i ];
  console.log(item.textContent)
  if( item.textContent === TEXT_CONTENT_PATTERN ){
    if( item.classList.contains( 'my-class-1' ) ){
      item.classList.remove( 'my-class-1' );
    }

    item.classList.add( 'my-class-2' );
  }
}
```

Или если условия точно такеи же как Вы и привели в вопросе, то можно записать короче -

```
document.body.querySelectorAll( '.my-class-1' )
.forEach( item => item.textContent === "user-2" ? item.className = "my-class-2" : null );
```

Или даже вот так -

```
document.body.querySelectorAll( '.my-class-1' )
.forEach( item => item.textContent === "user-2" && (item.className = "my-class-2") );
```